# Python IF query

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a program which calculates entrance costs.. I have managed to do it except from one part which requires if two adults and three childeren then the cost is $15. Should this be done using an if statement and how would I do it?

```
import math 

loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:

    print "Welcome"

    print "What would you like to do?:"
    print " "
    print "1) Calculate entrance cost"

    print "2) Leave swimming centre"
    print " "

    choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())
    if choice == 1:
        add1 = input("Adults: ")
        add2 = input("Concessions: ")
        add3 = input("Children: ")
        print add1, "+", add2, "+", add3, "answer=", add1 *5 + add2 *3 + add3 *2   
    elif choice == 2:
        loop = 0
```

Thank you for any help in advance, it will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Don't use a loop variable, just use `while True:` then `break` when you want the loop to end.

Comment: Use something like `if add1 == 2 and add3 == 3: print '$15'`. Then put the print statement in the `else:` after that.

Answer (score 1):

You should place an if statement for a special case, where you have the 2 adults, 3 children. Otherwise you should calculate it normally. I have commented the area where this special case occurs.

This code also assumes that the special case does not affect the price of the concessions.

```
import math 

loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:

    print "Welcome"

    print "What would you like to do?:"
    print " "
    print "1) Calculate entrance cost"

    print "2) Leave swimming centre"
    print " "

    choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())

    if choice == 1:
        add1 = input("Adults: ")
        add2 = input("Concessions: ")
        add3 = input("Children: ")

        cost = 0

        # special case for 2 adults, 3 children
        if add1 == 2 and add3 == 3:
            cost += 15
        else:
            cost += add1*5 + add3*2

        # concession cost
        cost += add2 *3

        print add1, "+", add2, "+", add3, "answer=", cost

    elif choice == 2:
        loop = 0
```

Comment: OK now, although *I* would prefer just the part of the code you changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math 

choice = 0
while True:

    print """
       Welcome

       What would you like to do?:

       1)Calculate entrance cost
       2) Leave swimming centre
      """

   choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())
   if choice == 1:
       add1 = input("Adults: ")
       add2 = input("Concessions: ")
       add3 = input("Children: ")
       print add1, "+", add2, "+", add3, "answer=", add1 *5 + add2 *3 + add3 *2   
   elif choice == 2:
       break
```